# HTML Table, colspan issue

Tags: html, html-table

I'm trying to create a table like this
[image: table i want to make]

And this is what I get when I run my HTML code
[image: erratic colspan]

The column width isn't same for the all the columns even after setting the colspan. Probably "colspan" attribute isn't working according to my expectation. What am I doing wrong?

My code:

```html
<table border="5" width="400" height = "400" table-layout = "auto">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4" align="center" style="width: 100%;">Colspan = “4”</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3" colspan="1" style="width: 25%;"> col1 </td>
    <td rowspan="3" colspan="1" style="width: 25%;"> col2 </td>
    <td rowspan="3" colspan="1" style="width: 25%;"> col3 </td>
    <td rowspan="3" colspan="1" style="width: 25%;"> col4 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" style="width: 50%;"> colspan = 2 </td>
    <td colspan="2" style="width: 50%;"> colspan = 2 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" style="width: 75%;"> colspan = 3</td>
    <td style="width: 25%;"> colspan = 1 </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It would help if you removed the [machine detectable errors](https://validator.nu) from your HTML.

Comment: This has nothing to do with colspan. The colspan is working correctly. It's not "straight" because your columns are different sizes. If you want them to be the same size you need to specify widths.

Comment: have you checked my code ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that it's not a colspan issue. I have just started learning HTML and did exactly what my book suggested. The book I'm following doesn't specify the width too but it works according to its screenshots. As the column width wasn't working according to my expectation, I thought it was due to colspan. Thank you

Comment: just copy and paste my code instead your code. exactly after check it comes whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Mr. Ravi Chauhan but I have yet to learn about Bootstrap

Comment: learn step by step https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/   if my answer is correct then please tick true flag then help to other which is true answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using bootstrap then it works automatically but below code is 100% works for you

```html
   <table  border="5">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4" align="center" style="width: 100%;">Colspan = “4”</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="3" colspan="1" style="width: 25%;"> col1 </td>
        <td rowspan="3" colspan="1" style="width: 25%;"> col2 </td>
        <td rowspan="3" colspan="1" style="width: 25%;"> col3 </td>
        <td rowspan="3" colspan="1" style="width: 25%;"> col4 </td>
      </tr>
      <tr></tr>
      <tr></tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="width: 50%;"> colspan = 2 </td>
        <td colspan="2" style="width: 50%;"> colspan = 2 </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3" style="width: 75%;"> colspan = 3</td>
        <td style="width: 25%;"> colspan = 1 </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
```

Comment: I mean this does work, but it's by far the least elegant solution. Being as you can fix this with literally one line.

Answer (score 3):

```css
td{
  min-width:100px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table border="5" width="400" height="400" table-layout="auto">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4" align="center">Colspan = “4”</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3" colspan="1"> col1 </td>
    <td rowspan="3" colspan="1"> col2 </td>
    <td rowspan="3" colspan="1"> col3 </td>
    <td rowspan="3" colspan="1"> col4 </td>

  </tr>

  <tr></tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"> colspan = 2 </td>
    <td colspan="2"> colspan = 2 </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td colspan="3"> colspan = 3</td>
    <td> colspan = 1 </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You should set `min-width` of table.

**Explanation**

Before explanation, I am not good at English, so if you can't understand my explanation, please reply.

You want to make same `width` each table's `td`.

And your table `width` is `400`, `column` is `4`.

So, each `column`'s `width` be set `100px`.

It's result you should set `min-width: 100px`

Comment: Thank you so much. That worked like a charm. The book I'm following doesn't specify the min-width too. Don't understand why that code works for them

Comment: @Sarvin It's my pleasure:) But I think `width: 25%` is better way to solve.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with your [colspan attributes. A colspan simply says this columns should be x columns wide in relation to the other columns in this table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td).

> This attribute contains a non-negative integer value that indicates
>   for how many columns the cell extends. Its default value is 1. Values
>   higher than 1000 will be considered as incorrect and will be set to
>   the default value (1)

It does not say how wide a column is. You need to specify that you want your columns evenly spaced. You could [specify a width in pixels](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46606567/542251). The disadvantage of this is that if you make your table bigger it'll not be equal again.

a better solution is to say that you expect a standard column to be 25% width (100%/4). you can do this using CSS:

```css
td{width:25%}
```

```html
<table border="5" width="400" height = "400" table-layout = "auto">
 <tr>
        <td  colspan = "4" align="center">Colspan = “4”</td>  <!--First row of the table-->      
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
        <td rowspan ="3" colspan = "1" > col1 </td>
        <td rowspan ="3" colspan = "1"> col2 </td>
        <td rowspan ="3" colspan = "1"> col3 </td>  <!--Second group of rows of the table consisting 3 rows-->  
        <td rowspan ="3" colspan = "1"> col4 </td>
        
    </tr>
    
    <tr></tr>   <!--occupied by the second group of rows of the table-->  
    <tr></tr>   <!--occupied by the second group of rows of the table-->

    <tr>
       <td colspan = "2"> colspan = 2 </td>  <!--3rd row which should contain 2 
                                             equal columns-->
       <td colspan ="2" > colspan = 2 </td> 
    </tr>

     <tr>   
       <td colspan="3"> colspan = 3</td> <!--4th row of which the first should 
                                         contain 3 cols and the second col is 1-->
       <td > colspan = 1 </td> 
     </tr>   
     </table>
```

Note: Even though some of your rows have less than 4 columns 25% still works because the browser will add the colspan rows up to compute the colspan width, so a colspan of 2 with have a width of 50%, etc.

Comment: Wish I could mark it as another answer too! Thank you so much

Answer (score -1):

Used bellow i have just added cellpadding=0 and cellspacing=0 and changed border =1

```html
    <table  cellpadding="0"  cellspacing="0" border="1" width="400" height = "400" table-layout = "auto">
        <tr>
            <td  colspan = "4" align="center">Colspan = “4”</td>  <!--First row of the table-->      
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
            <td rowspan ="3" colspan = "1" > col1 </td>
            <td rowspan ="3" colspan = "1"> col2 </td>
            <td rowspan ="3" colspan = "1"> col3 </td>  <!--Second group of rows of the table consisting 3 rows-->  
            <td rowspan ="3" colspan = "1"> col4 </td>
        
        </tr>
        
        <tr></tr>   <!--occupied by the second group of rows of the table-->  
        <tr></tr>   <!--occupied by the second group of rows of the table-->
        
        <tr>
           <td colspan = "2"> colspan = 2 </td>  <!--3rd row which should contain 2 
                                                 equal columns-->
           <td colspan ="2" > colspan = 2 </td> 
        </tr>
        
         <tr>   
           <td colspan="3"> colspan = 3</td> <!--4th row of which the first should 
                                             contain 3 cols and the second col is 1-->
           <td > colspan = 1 </td> 
         </tr>   
         </table>
```

Comment: That produces identical results

Comment: @liam explain me.what is identical for mine code.. there is different result as compared with the issue. because cellpadding and cellspacing generate space and padding on the table i have added these attribute also changed the border width.

Comment: I've added the snippet (again) press Run code. It's looks the same as the one in  the question. the issue is the width of the cols, not border, etc.